# como eu tiro esse erro da página com esse código?

Tags: php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST"){
    $file  = isset($_FILES["file"])?$_FILES["file"]:"";
}
$dir ="upload4";

if(!is_dir($dir)){
   mkdir($dir);
    echo "Pasra criada com sucesso";
}

move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"]);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No operador ternário poderia colocar um `exit` caso não exista nenhum arquivo, assim o código para e não mostra erro

Comment: em qual parte ficaria o exit?

Answer (score 2):

Coloque um "@" na frente da linha para ocultar o erro mas não é muito recomendado.
A melhor forma era usar um `isset`

Comment: mas eu já estou usando o isset

Comment: Linha 17: move_uploaded_file(isset($file["tmp_name"]),$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. isset($file["name"]));

Comment: Linha 17 Method @ (não recomendado): @move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"]);

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST" && isset($_FILES["file"])){
    //Se o método for post e houver um arquivo atribui o arquivo à variável
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
} else {
    //Se não mostra algo na tela e para o código
    echo "Método não é POST ou n]ao existe um arquivo";
    exit;
}

$dir ="upload4";

if(!is_dir($dir)){
    mkdir($dir);
    echo "Pasra criada com sucesso";
}

move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente declarar a sua variável `$file` com escopo global. Ela deve estar indefinida porque seu primeiro uso acontece dentro de um if.

Verifique também se os seus arquivos têm permissão de escrita no diretório do seu projeto para poderem criar diretórios em tempo de execução. Testei em ambiente Linux e funcionou.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php
$file = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST"){
    $file  = isset($_FILES["file"])?$_FILES["file"]:"";
}
$dir ="upload4";

if(!is_dir($dir)){
   mkdir($dir);
    echo "Pasra criada com sucesso";
}

if (!empty($file)) {
move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"]);
}
```

Coloque também um if para verificar se a variável $file está vazia. Isso evita que você tenha `Warning: Illegal string offset 'tmp_name'`